# StaticImage not showing up in test render in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby, react-testing-library

I have been searching through google for this for about an hour and have decided that I will likely need more direct assistance instead of just looking at other people's post.

My goal is to be able to have a jest test using this library https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library to be able to use the 'render' function and check that a StaticImage component inside of a custom component is rendered.

Currently this is my NavBar.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';
import Test from '../Test/Test';

const NavBar: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <nav data-testid="nav-bar">
      <Test siteTitle="TestssS" />
      <StaticImage src="../../images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

And this is my NavBar.test.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import NavBar from './NavBar';

describe('Ensuring NavBar is Rendered', () => {
  test('Ensuring Navbar is in the page', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<NavBar />);
    expect(getByTestId('nav-bar')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

describe('Squarehook logo is inside navbar', () => {
  test('Ensure Logo is in Navbar', async () => {
    const { getByAltText } = await render(<NavBar />);
    expect(getByAltText('Logo')).toBeInTheDocument;
  });
});
```

The test I am talking about is the 'Ensure Logo is in Navbar' test at the bottom. Ideally, I'd be rendering the NavBar component which would have the StaticImage component. Theoritically once StaticImage has completed rendering there would be an img tag with the alt attribute of 'Logo'.

However once I run npm test I get this result:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the alt text: Logo

Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
<body>
<div>
<nav
    data-testid="nav-bar"
>
    <h1
    class="header"
    data-testid="test"
    >
    TestssS
    </h1>
</nav>
</div>
</body>

13 |   test('Ensure Logo is in Navbar', async () => {
14 |     const { getByAltText } = await render(<NavBar />);
> 15 |     expect(getByAltText('Logo')).toBeInTheDocument;
    |            ^
16 |   });
17 | });
18 |

at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:38:19)
at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:90:38
at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:62:17
at getByAltText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:111:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/compontents/NavBar/NavBar.test.tsx:15:12)
```

You can see from the log above that the nav and the Test component get rendered, but for some reason there is no StaticImage/Img element at this point in time. I was reading a resource that said I may have needed to add await to those commands so I tried that on all of them but without any success.

I am using Gastby with Typescript.

the packages that are related to this is the
gatsby-plugin-image and the @testing-library/react.

I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: As an update to this question, I believe I'm asking the wrong question. I believe StaticImage isn't appearing not because it's a special component that doesn't render but because when the StaticImage component attempts to access a png file locally, Jest attempts to mock it. It appears the actual problem is that the mocking seems to be causing a Image not found error inside of StaticImage that results in it not rendering. I will likely create a new stackoverflow question asking for that specifically. Additional img tags pointing at static folder testing works!